# How to print UITableview content data in multiple pages in c# monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am printing all the data in UITableview, its working fine but if the content is too long all the content is displaying in single page, so I want to print data in multiple pages depending upon the tableview content.

Here is my code

```
            float x = tableView.Frame.X;
            float y = tableView.Frame.Y;
            float w = tableView.Frame.Width;
            float h = tableView.ContentSize.Height;

            tableView.Frame = new RectangleF (x, y, w, h);

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(tableView.Bounds.Size); 

            CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext(); 
            //ctx.FillRect(canvasRect); 
            tableView.Layer.RenderInContext(ctx); 

            UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext(); 
            NSData imgData = newImage.AsPNG(); 

            var printInfo = UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;

            printInfo.JobName = "Test: PDF Print";

            var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;

            printer.PrintingItems = imgData;
            printer.ShowsPageRange = true;
            //printer.PrintFormatter = textFormatter;
            printer.Present (true, (handler, completed, err) => {
                if (!completed && err != null){
                    Console.WriteLine ("error");
                }
            }   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to provide a PrintPageRenderer and use that to teach it how to print your data.

This sample shows how to do it:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/RecipesAndPrinting/RecipePrintPageRenderer.cs